# What are the limitations of memoization?

Tags: performance, optimization, memoization

Considering memoization for program performance optimization, it seems that in certain circumstances it could be very beneficial, since it removes the repeated computations completely. And there are a large number of existing language-level support in programming languages like Python, Java, C/C++, and so on. One of the example is a Python interpreter named IncPy. It could do automatic memoization and no extra work from programmer.

However, I don't think memoization is widely adopted in real world projects. And no big company has much interests on it either. So, what are the major limitations of it?

Any suggestions or ideas are welcomed and appreciated. The following are some limitations from my understanding:

1. slowdown in initial execution
2. space overhead
3. extra burdens on programmers, because it may require programmers to modify code

---

(I updated my question a little bit from here.)

Thanks for your comments. I guess among the three reasons I listed here, the third one is more important. Is this correct?

If you think memoization is indeed used widely, could you give me some examples, or  some keywords?

Thanks!

Comment: I think memoization *is* widely adopted, as are all sorts of similar caching techniques.

Comment: Java, C++, and *certainly* C lack language-level support. I think Python also has none but I could be out of date.

Comment: You're not going to use memoization everywhere - only on pure functions, only when you expect the function to be called repeatedly with the same arguments, and only when the space and code complexity costs of caching the results are low compared to the runtime savings - but when it's appropriate, we certainly use it.

Comment: Especially for dynamic programming algorithms, memoization is extremely important. Most of the time, though, it's not that applicable.

Comment: Memoisation as an optimisation technique is fine and not limited as you put it. I have used it to speed up code that used to run in 10 seconds which now runs in 0.03 seconds due to this technique. What is limited is the number of programmers who are taught it, who understand it, and know how to apply it ;).

Comment: when it fits (complicated or slow function with high likelihood of repeated parameters) it is great.  Built in with `lru_cache` or very easy to implement with a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example could be seen in a program for getting the febonacci series using recursion

```
function memoize(fn)
{
  const cache = {};
  return function(...args)
  {
    if (cache[args])
    {
      return cache[args];
    }

    const result = fn.apply(this, args);
    cache[args] = result;

    return result;
  };
}

function slowfib(n) {
  if(n < 2)
  {
    return n;
  }
  return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);

}

const fib = memoize(slowfib);
```

==-=======results with memoize=============
✓ Fib function is defined (3ms)
  ✓ calculates correct fib value for 1 (1ms)
  ✓ calculates correct fib value for 2
  ✓ calculates correct fib value for 3
  ✓ calculates correct fib value for 4
  ✓ calculates correct fib value for 15

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       6 passed, 6 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.118s
Ran all test suites matching /fib/test.js/i.

=========Results without Memoize=======
 PASS  fib/test.js
  ✓ Fib function is defined (3ms)
  ✓ calculates correct fib value for 1 (1ms)
  ✓ calculates correct fib value for 2
  ✓ calculates correct fib value for 3
  ✓ calculates correct fib value for 4
  ✓ calculates correct fib value for 15 (747ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       6 passed, 6 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.496s

See the time is taken for the last test and the total time

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of the caveats (not necessarily a limitation) is when the function that we are trying to memoize, can also return an error. In that case, caution must be take not to memoize the error.